# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null when i try to run my code in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

So when I try to run my html file in the browser chrome logs that error, but in visual studio code it doesn't register any problems. How can i fix this and ensure it doesn't happen in the future? My js code:

```js
const navbarBtn = document.querySelector("navbar__btn");
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector("navbar__links");
navbarBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let value = navbarLinks.classList.contains("navbar__collapse");

  if (value) {
    navbarLinks.classList.remove("navbar__collapse");
  } else {
    navbarLinks.classList.add("navbar__collapse");
  }
});
```

Comment: If the `navbar__btn` is a class put `.` in front of it if its an id add a `#` in front of it, currently its trying to select an element named `navbar__btn`

Comment: When is your script called? Any chance you are loading your script in the <head> section of your html file?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things potentially wrong with your code.

#### Script executed before html is ready

You need to make sure your JS is loaded after the required html is loaded. Without going in detail two good methods for that are:

loading the script at the bottom of the html file

```
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Using `defer` on your script

```
    <script defer src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
```

#### Your elements are not loaded correctly

In your example you are trying to access your DOM elements like this:

```
const navbarBtn = document.querySelector("navbar__btn");
```

However, this is looking for a custom tag `<navbar__btn>`. I believe it is more likely that you are looking for a tag with the class of "navbar__btn" so you have to add a point to refer to a class.

```
const navbarBtn = document.querySelector(".navbar__btn");
```

Comment: Good mention. Scripts should always be executed after body tags in the end.

Answer (score 0):

For a jquery code to run, it must always be enclosed within $(), which you have missed in navbarBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {

Try this:

```
const navbarBtn = document.querySelector("navbar__btn");
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector("navbar__links");
$(navbarBtn).addEventListener("click", function () {
let value = navbarLinks.classList.contains("navbar__collapse");

if (value) {
     navbarLinks.classList.remove("navbar__collapse");
 } else {
 navbarLinks.classList.add("navbar__collapse");
    } 
});
```

Also, you really don't need to the addEventListener function as Jquery automatically detects if you click on a button.

This code should also work:

```
$(navbarBtn).on('click,function(){ 
    // your logic here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, it is not finding the node that you are trying to attach the event to. So it has to be associated to the working of the `document.querySelector()` method.

You might want to send an `id` or `class` of the node, but this is not the right way to pass values of `id` and `class`.

You should rewrite you code as

```
// If you are passing id    
const navbarBtn = document.querySelector("#navbar__btn");
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector("#navbar__links");


// If you are passing class
const navbarBtn = document.querySelector(".navbar__btn");
const navbarLinks = document.querySelector(".navbar__links");
```

Remember you will get the first element in case you have passed `class` as argument.